# Magic .css doesn't change when uploaded via FTP

Tags: html, css, wordpress

When I change my enigma-theme.css and upload it via FTP, the website doesn't change. When I inspect the page's source I still get `text-transform: uppercase;` on line 82.

Comment: Any other information?

Comment: What would you like to know? It should be easy, just change the .css and upload. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I also tried modifying media-responsive.css
According to firebug that was the file responsible for the uppercase in my menu.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What does firebug says after you modified the other css? Does that worked?

Answer (score 0):

It is a cache problem: add *'?' . filemtime('/path/to/your/css/file')* at the end of the stylesheet src.

Example of the result :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/desktop/css/style.css?1452515969" type="text/css" />
```

The filemtime change every time you modify your file so the browser think that's a new file and doesn't use its cache.
Do it for all css and js files.

Comment: Okay, great! I thought it was something with cache. How do I find my filetime or version plz?

Comment: It's the filemtime function as I said you.
Can you edit your question adding your php code that generates the html page if you want me to correct it ?

Answer (score -1):

try changing to : text-transform: uppercase!important;

if it changes  try to check if   `<?php wp_head(); ?>`

is the last thing before  `</head>`  in themes header.php

Comment: why the vote down ? in my case that was the problem ...it was a cache problem